# Array and latex- tools packages issues = File ended while scanning use of \@newenv. \RequirePackage

Tags: packages, arrays, latextools, mdpi

I am trying to use the MDPI journal latex template, however, I keep on having this error "File ended while scanning use of @newenv. \RequirePackage" regarding the package "array". I have checked and found out that it was now included in "latex-tools", I installed the package "latex-tools". But it did not resolve the issue, please what should I do to solve this issue?

https://www.mdpi.com/data/MDPI_template.zip?v=20221213

Below is some part of .cls code

```
  %% IDENTIFICATION \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
  \ProvidesClass{Definitions/mdpi}[09/12/2022 MDPI paper class]
 
  %% PRELIMINARY DECLARATIONS \LoadClass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \RequirePackage{calc} \RequirePackage{indentfirst}
 \RequirePackage{fancyhdr} \RequirePackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
 \RequirePackage{lastpage} \RequirePackage{ifthen}
 \RequirePackage[right]{lineno} \RequirePackage{float}
 \RequirePackage{amsmath} \RequirePackage{array} % For table array
 \RequirePackage{tabularx} \RequirePackage{amssymb} % For math
 environment bold format \RequirePackage{setspace}
 \RequirePackage{enumitem} \RequirePackage{mathpazo}
 \RequirePackage{booktabs} % For \toprule etc. in tables
 \RequirePackage{titlesec} \RequirePackage{etoolbox} % For
 \AtBeginDocument etc. \RequirePackage{tabto} % To use tab for
 alignment on first page \RequirePackage{xcolor, colortbl} % To provide
 color for soul (for english editing), for adding cell color of table
 \RequirePackage{soul} % To highlight text
 \newcommand{\highlighting}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
 \RequirePackage{multirow} \RequirePackage{microtype} % For command
 \textls[]{} \RequirePackage{tikz} % For \foreach used for Orcid icon
 \RequirePackage{totcount} % To enable extracting the value of the
 counter "page"  \RequirePackage{changepage} % To adjust the width of
 the column for the title part and figures/tables (adjustwidth
 environment) \RequirePackage{attrib} % For XML2PDF use \tag{} for
 equation \RequirePackage{upgreek} % For making greek letters not
 italic \RequirePackage{pbox} % For biography environment
 \RequirePackage{ragged2e} % For command \justifying
 \RequirePackage[]{tocloft} % For dots in TOC. If subfigure package is
 loaded, the subfigure option needs to be added here to avoid clash:
 \RequirePackage[subfigure]{tocloft} \RequirePackage{marginnote} % For
 left column \reversemarginpar % To have the left column on the left
 side \RequirePackage{marginfix} % For command \clearmargin for
 manually moving the left column to the next page
 \RequirePackage{enotez} % For endnotes
 
 %% MORE DECLARATIONS
 
 %%%% Maths environments \RequirePackage{amsthm}
 \newtheoremstyle{mdpi}% name {12pt}% space above {12pt}% space below
 {\itshape}% body font {}% indent amount 1 {\bfseries}% theorem head
 font {.}% punctuation after theorem head {.5em}% space after theorem
 head {}% theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
 
 \renewcommand{\qed}{\unskip\nobreak\quad\qedsymbol} %% This places the
 symbol right after the text instead of placing it at the end on the
 line.
 
 \renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par %% \proofname allows to
 have "Proof of my theorem"   \pushQED{\qed}%   \normalfont
 \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax   \trivlist   \item[\hskip\labelsep
         \bfseries %% "Proof" is bold
     #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces %% Period instead of colon }{%   \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse }
 
  \theoremstyle{mdpi}  \newcounter{theorem}  \setcounter{theorem}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Theorem}[theorem]{Theorem}    \newcounter{lemma} 
 \setcounter{lemma}{0}  \newtheorem{Lemma}[lemma]{Lemma}   
 \newcounter{corollary}  \setcounter{corollary}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Corollary}[corollary]{Corollary}   
 \newcounter{proposition}  \setcounter{proposition}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Proposition}[proposition]{Proposition}   
 \newcounter{characterization}  \setcounter{characterization}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Characterization}[characterization]{Characterization}   
 \newcounter{property}  \setcounter{property}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Property}[property]{Property}    \newcounter{problem} 
 \setcounter{problem}{0}  \newtheorem{Problem}[problem]{Problem}   
 \newcounter{example}  \setcounter{example}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Example}[example]{Example}   
 \newcounter{examplesanddefinitions} 
 \setcounter{examplesanddefinitions}{0} 
 \newtheorem{ExamplesandDefinitions}[examplesanddefinitions]{Examples
 and Definitions}    \newcounter{remark}  \setcounter{remark}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Remark}[remark]{Remark}    \newcounter{definition} 
 \setcounter{definition}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Definition}[definition]{Definition}   
 \newcounter{hypothesis}  \setcounter{hypothesis}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Hypothesis}[hypothesis]{Hypothesis}
 
  \newcounter{notation}  \setcounter{notation}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Notation}[notation]{Notation}    \newcounter{assumption} 
 \setcounter{assumption}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Assumption}[assumption]{Assumption}   
 \newcounter{algorithm}  \setcounter{algorithm}{0} 
 \newtheorem{Algorithm}[algorithm]{Algorithm}    % Define left/right
 mark in math environment \let\originalleft\left
 \let\originalright\right
 \renewcommand{\left}{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\originalleft}
 \renewcommand{\right}{\aftergroup\egroup\originalright
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please, instead of code image code of the complete small document, which we can test in our computers. Why you use `\RequirePackage` for thrir loading? Dose usual `\usepackage` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Zarko the question is showing a fragment of the journal class

Comment: I don't get that error, but a different one, because `lineno` has to be loaded after `amsmath`. Please, report to the class maintainers.

Comment: Okay thank you @egreg

Comment: Please use the `{}` for code not block quotes. If you are on a PC you can also just mark the code in the editor and press ctrl-k, that indents all lines with 4 spaces and and thus the code is preformatted and line breaks etc survives.

Comment: Thank you @deleif